# What does this message mean: "isS4" is not a BUILTIN function?

Tags: r, lme4

I installed the `lme4` package and tried to run `example(glmer)` but got the error message:

```
Error in function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
"isS4" is not a BUILTIN function
```

However, when I run `builtins()[590]`, R returns `"isS4"`, which leads me to believe that, whatever a BUILTIN function is, `isS4` ought to be one. I searched for the error message online and found a question about it on LinkedIn, this time from someone who was trying to install R Commander, with no answers. I noticed that we were both using R 2.15.2 and wondered if this problem has to do with the compatability of packages with different versions of R.

I'm really interested to know whether there is a way round the error, and what caused it exactly.

Comment: It may mean you failed to load the package you installed: `?library; ?install.packages` .... not the same functions.

Comment: No, I already did `library(lme4)` before trying to run the `example(glmer)`.

Comment: What version of R are you running?

Comment: I noticed that we were both using R 2.15.2 and wondered if this problem has to do with the compatability of packages with different versions of R.

Comment: The only way to tell is for you to post the results of `sessionInfo()`. I get no error with R version 3.0.1 Patched and lme4_0.99999911-6. At the moment, the location of isS4 in the builtins() vector is 585.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a backward-compatibility problem with version 2.15.2. It's hard for me to test since I don't have a copy of 2.15.2 installed locally.  Can you do a bit of debugging (with `debug()`, or `traceback()`, or `options(error=recover)` and comment/edit to let me/us know where the error occurred?  You can also post this as an issue at http://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues ...

Comment: also works for me on 64-bit-linux, R 2.15.3, with a fresh CRAN install of `lme4` ...

Comment: Thank you @BB. I know it is a compatability issue, but I am trying to find out what caused the error message. Your `debug` hint was very helpful. The message is thrown by the `eval.c` function and I think it is triggered by a call to `rBind`, which makes sense given the error message.

Comment: have you tried re-installing the `Matrix` package?